# shortcut keys for starting a non-default terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can start a terminal this way on windows: `CTRL+SHIFT+P` > type "terminal" > select "Create new Integrated Terminal" option. This starts powershell since that is default. But how do I start off a bash terminal, or, a simple windows command prompt terminal instance using short cut keys?